# How do I quickly sort on multiple columns with the same stub names?

Tags: r

I have an data frame in wide format. I'd like to sort on the variables which have a common stub (in the case below, the x's), moving left to right.

```
    df <- data.frame(
            id = 1:10,
            x1 = rnorm(10,0,1),
            x2 = rnorm(10,0,1),
            x3 = rnorm(10,0,1),
            x4 = rnorm(10,0,1))
```

I'd like to do this efficiently, rather than typing:

```
attach(df)
df[order(x1,x2,x3,x4),]
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this please?

Comment: Try `df[do.call(order, df[-1]),]`

Comment: Or use `library(tidyr);df %>% arrange_at(vars(starts_with('x')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with `order` after subsetting the columns of interest in `base R`

```
 nm1 <- grep("^x\\d+$", names(df)) #identify the columns of interest
 df1 <- df[do.call(order, df[nm1]),]
```

---

Or we use `arrange_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
        arrange_at(vars(starts_with('x')))
```